# How can someone get 100 rep without linking accounts or getting upvoted?

Tags: support, reputation

The other day I ran across a guy who downvoted an answer of mine that was correct but included an extra paragraph of commentary which he apparently didn't like.  I was curious why someone would downvote an answer which they otherwise liked, so I checked out his profile to see if I could understand his reasoning by reading some of his answers and other comments.

He had 1 upvote, 1 downvote, 0 answers, 0 questions, 0 tags, and had only posted 1 comment (the one .  He joined 4 days before he downvoted me, and he doesn't seem to have any linked accounts with 200+ rep (the only obvious way I've read about so far which gives you 100 instant rep on one of the other sites without actually doing anything on that site).

I've probably already gotten more upvotes than I deserve for that particular answer, but I'm asking out of curiosity because it seems like this guy just hopped on and started voting right away, when others (including myself) had to answer several questions and begin to get a feel for the community before accumulating the 15 rep required to upvote.

Do you suppose he unlinked his accounts after getting the rep (do you lose your 100 points when you unlink your accounts?), or is there some way to earn 100 points without contributing on any of the Stack/Meta/Super/Server sites?  (Or did I miss something else completely obvious?)

Comment: So who's the Stig?

Comment: Did you see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13799/

Comment: @Eric: What's a Stig?

@Manni: looks like we ran across the same thing...it's 

Everyone has posted some good possibilities, so I'm upvoting all the answers so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/

You have probaly already seen the official information on this, but association is the only way currently to get an instance +100 rep without doing much else.

He might have had stuff deleted or removed, or associated before.

Comment: As I mentioned, he doesn't appear to have any linked accounts.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you lose the 100 points if you unassociate your account?  Or do you still get to keep the rep?

Comment: It might be one of those rep fixes that would be solved by a re calculate rep action.

Comment: I was bored and unassociated my accounts...sure enough, no points were docked.  When I associated the second time, I didn't get the +100, of course.

Answer (score 4):

I can't say for sure, but maybe the original linking account (+100) was deleted for inappropriate activity?

Answer (score 2):

He may have answered some questions, then deleted them. Or maybe *asked* some questions, then deleted them. You could ask a 10k or higher person to tell you if he has any deleted posts (which they should be able to view).